# Get and add all properties of type Mname from a list of objects and add them dynamically too a drop down

Tags: c#, linq, list, object, properties

Ok so I have an object type called monsters and a list of all monsters
I need to get all the strings from the property called MName and add each one to a Drop down text box.

here is the class so far.(sorry Im really new to coding.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Monsters
    {
        public string MonsterName { get; set; }
        public int MonsterAttackMin { get; set; }
        public int MonsterAttackMax { get; set; }
        public Monsters (string MName, int MAttackMin, int MAttackMax)
{
        MonsterName = MName;
        MonsterAttackMin = MAttackMin;
        MonsterAttackMax = MAttackMax;
}


        List<Monsters> monstersObjectList = new List<Monsters>
        {
             new Monsters("Blob",0,5){},
             new Monsters("Wolf",0,5){},

        };


        //foreach (List<Monsters>//**DontKnowPastHere** M in monsterObjectList)


       // Monsters Blob = new Monsters("Blob",0,5); 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `foreach` loop the type of your loop variable is the type of the items in the collection, so you want:

```
foreach (Monster m in monsterObjectList)
    ddlMonsters.Items.Add(new ListItem(m.MonsterName));
```

You could also bind the list as the data source:

```
ddlMonsters.DataSource = monsterObjectList;
ddlMonsters.DataTextField = "MonsterName"; 
ddlMonsters.DataBind();
```